# How to remove preference when installed donation application

Tags: android

I currently have two versions of my app, a paid one and a free one.
But i want remove donation preference when installed donation package..
any ideas for this?

This code is check installed donate app

```
public boolean isDonate() {
    try
    {
        PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.example.test.donate",
                PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        Log.d(TAG, "Pro app is installed: " + info.applicationInfo.name);
        return context.getPackageManager().checkSignatures("com.example.test",
                "com.example.test.donate") == PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH;
    }
    catch (NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

want to remove this preference

xml code:

```
<com.example.test.IconPreferenceScreen
    android:key="goto_pro"
    android:title="@string/go_to_pro"
    android:summary="@string/go_to_pro_summary" />
```

java code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    IconPreferenceScreen pro = (IconPreferenceScreen) findPreference("goto_pro");
    Resources res = getResources();
    Drawable icon = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.playstore);
    pro.setIcon(icon);

    getPreferenceManager()
       .findPreference("goto_pro")
       .setOnPreferenceClickListener(
          new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.example.test"));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your Preference Activity's onCreate:

```
Preference mPref = getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("goto_pro");
getPreferenceScreen().removePreference(mPref);
```